# BlockUI library blocks ui but, not load image while postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, blockui

I am using `jquery.blockUI` to block UI. It works fine and loading image when event is not postback event. When I am blocking UI while postback then it blocks UI but does not show loading image.

I am using following code to block UI.

```
$.blockUI({ message: '<here i am appending image tag src="loader.gif" >
            <div>' + msg + '</div><a class="unblock" href="javascript:void(0)">
            Cancel</a>' });
```

The path of the image is correct.

Is there any way to load image on postback?

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```
$.blockUI({ 
    message: $('#displayBox')
});
```

And in HTML add a div
`<div id="displayBox">Your image tag here within</div>`

**[Reference](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#demos)**

Comment: You can do something like this `$('#displayBox').html("Here your dynamic text");` and then `$.blockUI({ 
    message: $('#displayBox')
}); `